# Spring MVC controller custom parameter name

Tags: spring-mvc, controller

I have a Spring MVC controller. And I have in the method 50 parameters. All of the parameters have very specific name, for example: **FOO[]**. 
I don't want write 50 parameters in the method signature like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String test(
    @RequestParam(value = "FOO[]") String foo,
    @RequestParam(value = "BAR[]") String bar,
// Other 48 parameters
)
{
    return "test";
}
```

I want to map all the parameters on the one object, I mean, I want to write a simple bean class with getter/setter and use it like method parameter. 
But how can I set custom names to my class fields?

e.g.:

```
class FooBar {
    @SomeAnnotation_for_binding_the_field_to_my_field_FOO[]
    private String foo;
    private String bar;
    // Other 48 fields
    // getters/setters
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know annotations are kinda cool, but think rationally. You HAVE to enumerate, in code, all the mappings. There is nothing implicit about mapping FOO[] to foo, it seems to be beyond your control. Just take the parameters as a map (you can always ask Spring to give you map of all parameters) and do something like:

```
@RequestMapping
public String test(@RequestParam Map<String, Object> map) {
    MyObject mo = new MyObject();
    mo.setFoo(map.get("FOO[]").toString());
    mo.setBar(map.get("WOBBLE13[][]").toString);
    return "whatever";
}
```

If you want to make this process more automatic, and if there exists an alorithm that maps parameter names to property names, you can use Spring's bean wrapper:

```
@RequestMapping
public String test(@RequestParam Map<String, String> map) {
   BeanWrapper bw = new BeanWrapperImpl(new MyObject);
   for (Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
       bw.setProperty(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
   }
}

private static String decodeName(String n) {
    return n.toLowerCase().substring(0,n.length() - 2);
}
```

You could make the process even more automatic by using a different Binder, you could (really, not a problem) add some custom annotations... but really, there is no point, if you just have a single case of 50 params. If you insist, add a comment.

Answer (score 0):

THis sounds like a good time to use a hashmap, with key as the var name and value as value. Wrap that in a form backing object.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a resource class i.e FooBarResource.jave and in your controller use that as a request body something like the following:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@Secured({"ROLE_ADMIN"})
    public ResponseEntity<ModelMap> createTest(@Valid @RequestBody FooBarResource body, UriComponentsBuilder builder) {
```

Comment: And how can I named my field **FOO[]** in Java? :)

Comment: you had a FooBar class all i done just renamed it :) you could use the same class as your resource class. If you wanted any fields in the controller you just do body.getFoo() for example. you could also do things like @NotNull(message = "foo is mandatory") on foo in your resource class.